# Type androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter is defined multiple times

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

My Android project contains several build flavours. I can build project with any of them without any issue but I get error if I try to build all build flavours together with `./gradlew assemble`

```
> Task :app:mergeExtDexProdGameDebug FAILED
ERROR:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/b6b5144c335ca1995bdbde58df8eedc5/viewpager-1.0.0-runtime/classes.dex: D8: Type androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter is defined multiple times: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/b6b5144c335ca1995bdbde58df8eedc5/viewpager-1.0.0-runtime/classes.dex, /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/0b77b9baee4aa5906a31353c9936b901/viewpager-1.0.0-runtime/classes.dex
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
Type androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter is defined multiple times: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/b6b5144c335ca1995bdbde58df8eedc5/viewpager-1.0.0-runtime/classes.dex, /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/0b77b9baee4aa5906a31353c9936b901/viewpager-1.0.0-runtime/classes.dex
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:128)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:115)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:111)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.merge(DexMergingTask.kt:805)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.run(DexMergingTask.kt:760)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:67)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:60)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:200)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/b6b5144c335ca1995bdbde58df8eedc5/viewpager-1.0.0-runtime/classes.dex
        at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_2.2.64.java:0)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.a0.a(SourceFile:89)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:11)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:113)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Type androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter is defined multiple times: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/b6b5144c335ca1995bdbde58df8eedc5/viewpager-1.0.0-runtime/classes.dex, /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/0b77b9baee4aa5906a31353c9936b901/viewpager-1.0.0-runtime/classes.dex
```

Cleaning of caches didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

As you said a solution is to invalidate the cache, and that's actually the only solution I know of.

Just make sure the JVM is closed before opening Android Studio again. There's a chance that JVM is stuck and prevents a dex file from deletion. So, what I'd suggest the following steps:

1. Open Task Manager, then do "End task" to all JVM you find (most likely it's `java.exe`) **OR** restart PC
2. Open Android Studio, then do "Invalidate cache and restart" **OR** delete the cache files manually.